# Error While Debugging

Tags: asp.net

I have one web application. while i debug the solution the rendering makes too slow and if i close the browser page i got one error like this

WebDev.WebServer.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

I got one information from attched proess is that this .exe file related to asp.net development server- port(port number).

How it can be resolved? please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot close the browser that opens when you are running debug for an ASP.NET program.

It renders slower because you are debugging it. This means the compiler has injected a lot of extra code need to make the application work with the debugger. There is no getting around this.